How do I use the ERCOT API to download a report? API only provides report metadata
Problem:
I am using the ERCOT Public API to get market data for an energy management project. Hitting the endpoint successfully returns only the report metadata. How do I download the entire report?
For example, I am hitting the endpoint, https://api.ercot.com/api/public-reports/np4-190-cd/dam_stlmnt_pnt_prices. The values I get back talk about the structure of the report.
{
    "report": {
        "reportName": "dam_stlmnt_pnt_prices",
        "reportDisplayName": "DAM Settlement Point Prices",
        "reportId": "12331",
        "reportEMIL": "NP4-190-CD",
        "downloadLimit": 2000000
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "deliveryDate",
            "label": "Delivery Date",
            "cardinality": 1,
            "dataType": "DATE",
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "hasRange": true
        },
        {
            "name": "hourEnding",
            "label": "Hour Ending",
            "cardinality": 2,
            "dataType": "VARCHAR",
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "hasRange": false
        },
        {
            "name": "settlementPoint",
            "label": "Settlement Point",
            "cardinality": 3,
            "dataType": "VARCHAR",
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "hasRange": false
        },
        {
            "name": "settlementPointPrice",
            "label": "Settlement Point Price",
            "cardinality": 4,
            "dataType": "DOUBLE",
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "hasRange": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DSTFlag",
            "label": "DST Flag",
            "cardinality": 5,
            "dataType": "BOOLEAN",
            "searchable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "hasRange": false
        }
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://api.ercot.com/api/public-reports/np4-190-cd/dam_stlmnt_pnt_prices"
        },
        "parent": {
            "href": "https://api.ercot.com/api/public-reports/np4-190-cd"
        }
    }
}

I found this link that may point to another API to download the report (https://developer.ercot.com/applications/ews/Report%20Messages/GetReports/). However, I am not sure how to use this or if it is correct.
